# Files disappear from assets

Tags: assets

EE 2.4
Assets 1.1.5

Following a server upgrade from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.4 all files in the Assets addon have gone from a clients installation. All the images in the channel entries have also vanished. Could you please tell me if a an upgrade to the latest version of Assets will solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets 1.1.5 reads files from the disk, so, most likely, this is a permission issue or an issue of wrong server path set for the upload folder.